# What's wrong with return here?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return

I'm working my way through eloquent javascript and for whatever reason return simply isn't working in the function nth.
I honestly don't understand why it isn't working. I know I'm pretty close to getting the recursive version on nth working. This bug makes no sense to me.
Here is all the relevant code:

```
function arrayToList(array) {
  list = null;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    var x = array[array.length -(i + 1)];
    list = {value: x, rest: list};
  } return list;
}

function listToArray(list) {
  var array = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
    array[i] = node.value;
    i += 1;
  }
  return array;
}  


//return statements are broken here
function nth(list, number) {
 if (number == 0) {
   //console.log(list.value);
   return element;
   var element = list.value;
   } else if (number > 0) {
     list = list.rest;
     number--;
     //console.log(number);
     //console.log(list);
     nth(list, number);
   } else {
     return "Something went wrong";
     console.log(number);
   }
}

console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1));
```

Can anyone explain why return statements aren't working in the in the nth function?

Comment: Your indentation seems a bit off...

Comment: `return nth(list, number);` in else if

Comment: The function call is working correctly. I moved the indentation and it doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: You should keep all those variables local with *var*: `for (i=0 ...)` is not eloquent.

Comment: I thought for( i = 0 ...) was local

Comment: you are missing the `var`. Always add a `var`. I suggest turning on strict mode which will throw an error if you miss simple stuff like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually **2** problems with your code.
Look at the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0wpdnn66/

- You have to define element before using it (exchange lines 24 and 25)
- You need to return from all branches. There is a `return` missing in line 31

```js
function arrayToList(array) {
  list = null;
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
    var x = array[array.length -(i + 1)];
    list = {value: x, rest: list};
  } return list;
}

function listToArray(list) {
  var array = [];
  var i = 0;
  for (var node = list; node; node = node.rest) {
    array[i] = node.value;
    i += 1;
  }
  return array;
}  


//return statements are broken here
function nth(list, number) {
 if (number == 0) {
   //console.log(list.value);
   var element = list.value;// <-- needs to be before return
   return element;
   } else if (number > 0) {
     list = list.rest;
     number--;
     //console.log(number);
     //console.log(list);
     return nth(list, number);// <-- needs return
   } else {
     return "Something went wrong";
     console.log(number);
   }
}

document.write(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1));
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why I needed the return to call the function again? I don't understand why I need to make both of these changes, the function was calling itself correctly without it.

Comment: Because otherwise you lose the result of the function (it returns `undefined`)

Comment: it was calling itself, but not returning anything to your original call. The problem is that the recursively called function will (maybe) return a value to the function you called. Then the function you called from outside the recursive loop will have to return the result. Without a return statement, it will not do so.

Comment: Is there a resource that explains how return works? I didn't know that it did that

Comment: Well, overlooking stuff happens to all of us  ;)

Comment: @RobG sry, didn't know about that feature. I edited my post :)

Answer (score 2):

You use `return` before assigning a value to `element`, which means because of [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) `element` is declared, but `undefined`.

```
if (number == 0) {
   //console.log(list.value);
   return element;
   var element = list.value;
```

Should be

```
if (number == 0) {
   //console.log(list.value);
   var element = list.value;

   return element;
```

And since I guess you only defined element so that you could log it before returning, you could do this more simply (as [Joe Frambach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1253312/joe-frambach) pointed out)

```
if (number == 0) {
   return list.value;
```

Also in the following `else if` it needs to return the `nth`'s call result.

So that becomes

```
} else if (number > 0) {
     list = list.rest;
     number--;
     //console.log(number);
     //console.log(list);
     return nth(list, number);
```

Comment: or cut to the chase and `return list.value`

Comment: Yup seems legit here

Comment: Thanks for the response. I corrected that and return still doesn't work

Comment: @Steve Updated my answer

Comment: That solution does work, but  I don't understand why I need to return the call

Comment: @Steve Recursive calls are in a top to bottom and up again fashion, you solve smaller and smaller problems until you you hit the bottom, and to go back up, you need every single subproblem to return its local solution

Comment: that makes sense. Do you know of any good resources that explain what return actually does?

Comment: @Steve Stack overflow probably holds some answers about misunderstanding of return statements. The return concept is for a function to provide an assignable value for the place where you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes:

```
function nth(list, number) {
  if (number == 0) {
    var element = list.value; // <- this goes above the return
    return element;
  } else if (number > 0) {
    list = list.rest;
    number--;
    return nth(list, number); // <- you need to add a return statement here
  } else {
    return "Something went wrong";
  }
}
```

With this change:

```
console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 0)); // returns 10
console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 1)); // returns 20
console.log(nth(arrayToList([10, 20, 30]), 2)); // returns 30
```

You are basically iterating over a linked list using recursion.  `number` is the number of nodes that you want to skip.  If `number` is 0, we want to return that value.  If `number` is 1, we want to skip one node.  This is what the `else if` part of your code is doing.  It's skipping the current node, and returning the remainder of the nodes.

To jump to the next node you do `nth(list.rest, --number)`.  You do this continually until number reaches 0, which gets you the value you actually want.

Eventually when `number` is 1, the return statement in the `else if` part of your code will be `return nth(list.rest, 0)`, which returns the actual value you want.  And this is why you return that value.

Just for fun, here's a version that doesn't use recursion:

```
function nth(list, number) {
  if (number < 0) return;

  for (var curr = list; curr && number > 0; number--) {
    curr = curr.rest;
  }

  if (curr) return curr.value;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you explain why I needed the return to call the function again? I don't understand why I need to make both of these changes, the function was calling itself correctly without it.

Comment: You are basically iterating over a linked list using recursion.  Number is the number of nodes that you want to skip... so to jump to the next node you do `nth(list.rest, --number)`... and you do this continually until number reaches 0.  And thats the value you eventually want. Because of recursion, the return statement will eventually return the correct value, because you will eventually get to `nth(list.rest, 0)` which returns the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent both issues (var element declared at the wrong place and missing return) by removing the var and using a ternary expression. That's a general coding style advice: less `var` and less `return` => less trouble.
Your function boils to a one-liner:

```
function nth(list, number) {
  return number <= 0 ? list.value : nth(list.rest, number-1);
}
```

Comment: Man... that downvote without explanation is not helpful.

Comment: Not my down vote, but code–only answers aren't helpful. You need to explain why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it.

Comment: It should be `nth(list.rest, --number)` as `number--` decrements the number after passing the variable value to the function.  Also, a statement on the first line such as `if (number < 0 || !list) return;` will avoid index out of bounds issues. Also not my downvote

Comment: @RobG @br3nt thanks for your comments, I'll improve the answer. I thought that as the issues had already been explained, it was not necessary to repeat them. @br3nt " index out of bounds issues": if number < 0 `nth` will returns `undefined`, so no need for a specific check.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this will work

```
function arrayToList(array) {
    var list = null;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var x = array[array.length - (i + 1)];
        list = {
            value: x,
            rest: list
        };
    }

    return list;
}

//return statements are broken here
function nth(list, nr) {
    if (nr === 0) {
        return list.value;
    } else if (nr > 0) {
        list = list.rest;
        nr--;
        return nth(list, nr);
    }
}

var list = arrayToList([10, 20, 30]);
var nthNr = nth(list, 1);
console.log(nthNr);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to return "something went wrong" you need to check if `list` is not null before accessing its properties. Effectively this checks to see if `number` has not exceeded its upper bound and avoids throwing a TypeError if it does. For example and including a check on the lower bound of `number`,

```
function nth(list, number) {
    if( number < 0 || !list)
        return "Something went wrong";
    if (number == 0) {
        return list.value;
    }
    return nth(list.rest, --number);
 }
```

Issues of setting `element` before the return statement (not used above) and returning values from recursive calls (as above) have already been covered in comments and answers.